# find the average between object values to use as a value for another object key in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I find the average between the scores of the 2 games all within the same object?

```js
var scores = {
   game1 : 55,
   game2 : 62,
   average: ?
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of games is fixed, you can do very simply:

```js
var scores = {
  game1: 55,
  game2: 62,
}
scores.average = (scores.game1 + scores.game2) / 2;
console.log(scores);
```

If the number of games isn't fixed, you can loop through the properties of the object and add each value to an array, then calculate the sum of the array and divide by its length to get the average.

```js
var scores = { game1 : 55, game2 : 62}
var scoreArr = [];
for(const a in scores){
  scoreArr.push(scores[a]);
}
scores.average = scoreArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / scoreArr.length;
console.log(scores);
```

Comment: Hi Spectric, what about if it was an object with objects?

Comment: @illy Depends what you mean. What does the object look like?

Comment: Hi Spectric, I edited my original question up above^.  Thanks!

Comment: @illy I would recommend posting a new question in this case - it's more organized and efficient than editing a question over and over again. I'll make sure to leave an answer if you do :)

Comment: Ok I posted it under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386944/self-reference-in-object-literals .  Spectric, you are awesome!