# Self reference in object literals

Tags: javascript, object

How do I find the average score between the 2 games in each week?

```
var scores = {
   week1: {
       game1 : 55,
       game2 : 62,
       average: ?
   },
   week2: {
       game1 : 71,
       game2 : 67
       average: ?
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`for... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement to iterate through the properties of the object and calculate the average individually by summing the scores for game1 and game2 and dividing by 2.

```js
var scores = {
  week1: {
    game1: 55,
    game2: 62,
  },
  week2: {
    game1: 71,
    game2: 67
  }
};

for (const x in scores) scores[x].average = (scores[x].game1 + scores[x].game2) / 2;

console.log(scores);
```

Comment: Amazing Spectric thank you!  I'll click accept once the time allows.  I wish you great success!

Comment: @illy No problem :). Glad to help.